# Reading from a database that is stored on a laptop for user authentication

Tags: android, sqlite, authentication

Im building an app that requires the user to login with and ID and Password. Since we cannot create the database on the user's phone to store all this info (security reasons) I'm thinking to have a database stored on a laptop (ideally server) to hold user details. I want my app to access this db (which will be on the laptop im working on at the moment) and validate the user?

Any idea how or suggestions to start with? I'm not sure how to let the app read from a locally stored db (not on the phone but on the laptop im buildin the app on).

Kindest regards

Saeed

Comment: Why is it going to be more secure to put the database on a laptop as opposed to the phone?

Comment: i was thinking that the user details db should be ideally on a server(my laptop in this case). so when a user is tryin to login in, the app should access that db and validate the user. right?

Comment: That doesn't answer "why is a server more secure than the phone" especially when interacting with a server means putting information out over a network.

Comment: im not saying its more secure. sorry if i miss phrased my question. but logically you have to have a db or xml to hold user data. and it cannot be on the phone. If i keep it on the phone it means any user can manipulate the data or gain access to it.

Comment: +1 @cjk -- if security is really the only reason, then avoid the complexity of sending credentials over the network.

Comment: Any user that can get access to you app's data can also get access to the app itself.

Comment: @cjk, i think im getting your point now. since the data in the db is only about the user only (and owner of the phone) .. then i shouldn't worry to much about keeping all user info externally. is that what you are trying to explain?  thanks for your responses

Comment: I think it is more likely that someone will be able to get the data out of the server (laptop) than it will for them to get the data out of the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is to use an AMPP ( Apache, MySQL, PHP, PERL) server. Build the database as SQL and provide an API using PHP and Apache for the phone to connect. But be sure to use a safe way to encrypt or hide the information change between the phone and server (either encrypt data on the phone and then send it or use a safe protocol).

Comment: Thanks for your respond.. that sounds complicated but it's a starting point at least. I will look into it. many regards

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't phrased well enough for me to know if this is a good suggestion, but you might look in to [OpenID](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID).

Comment: Sorry about that.. but i;ll check your suggestion. Many regards